# c++ give no warning or error when a integer is passed to a function that has char arguments

Tags: c++, compilation

Why does c++ give no warning or error when a integer is passed to a function that takes char arguments.

```
void test(char a) {
    std::cout << a;
}


test(1);
```

I would get unexpected behaviour doing so(ie a ? is getting printed). But I was expecting this to be an error or atleast a compilation warning as some sort of cast was happening. Why is this not happening?

Comment: 1 is not '1'(usually = 49) but still valid char value.

Comment: oh got it, feel so dumb now

Comment: `int` can implicitly convert to `char`, and vice versa. `int i = '0';` is valid code, and has been useful to me in the past

Comment: Some compilers will warn - depends on the value passed - live - https://godbolt.org/z/TK6h87cjd

Comment: There is no **cast** happening the code. There is a **conversion**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure *why* `c++` allow implicit conversion here, maybe because it's good for dealing with raw memory.

---

For why you get unexpected behavior

`1` is a valid [control code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#SOH) like `'\0'` or `'\n'`

while you should use `'1'` (or `49`, assume ASCII or compatible format)

---

Compiler would warn if it does not fit in.

```cpp
void test(char c);
void F(){test(1);} // OK
void G(){test(10000);} // warning 
void H(int v){test(v);} // need -Wconversion
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jT3WYWxdo)

Comment: Don't use 49; don't assume ASCII. There's no need for that.

Comment: @PeteBecker well probably no need for `'1'`, but one do need to assume (or specify) the encoding, especially for Unicode.